# Is there a way to get a <button> element to link to a location without wrapping it in an <a href ... tag?

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink

Just wondering if there is a way to get a HTML `<button>` element to link to a location without wrapping it in an `<a href...` tag?

Button currently looks like:

```
<button>Visit Page Now</button>
```

What I would prefer **not** to have:

```
<a href="link.html"><button>Visit Page Now</button></a>
```

The button is not being used within a form so `<input type="button">` is not an option. I am just curious to see if there is a way to link this particular element without needing to wrap it in an `<a href` tag.

Looking forward to hearing some options/opinions.

Comment: @robertc, I normally use a link but then what's the point of a <button> element?

Comment: The point of a button element is to trigger a script function, like recalculating delivery costs on a form or applying bold formatting to selected text, that isn't supported natively by HTML.  Navigating between pages is something that's supported by HTML, you don't need script to do it, therefore you don't need a button.

Comment: Besides, wrapping a `<button>` in a `<a>` doesn't work in IE.  The purpose of a button anywhere other than a form is to perform some scripted action.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Inline Javascript:

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://www.example.com';">Visit Page Now</button>
```

Defining a function in Javascript:

```
<script>
    function visitPage(){
        window.location='http://www.example.com';
    }
</script>
<button onclick="visitPage();">Visit Page Now</button>
```

or in Jquery

```
<button id="some_id">Visit Page Now</button>

$('#some_id').click(function() {
  window.location='http://www.example.com';
});
```

Comment: Thanks @aiham, this worked. To make it more flexible, the url should be a argument to the visitPage function.

Comment: I'm using **ASP.NET MVC**. How can I `POST` the data and direct to **Controller's** another **Action Method**?

Comment: This is a misleading answer as a link element would be the desired element. Separate functionality and design when choosing elements!

Answer (score 28):

Here's a solution which will work even when JavaScript is disabled:

```
<form action="login.html">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

The trick is to surround the button with its own `<form>` tag.

I personally prefer the `<button>` tag, but you can do it with `<input>` as well:

```
<form action="login.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: One problem: Any URL parameters in the `action` attribute value will get stripped off, because `get`-method forms (and forms default to `get` method) are expected to provide their own parameters. For example, `<form action="https://example.com/foo?bar=1"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></form>` will send the user instead to just "`https://example.com/foo?`". The user will be sent to the correct URL if you set an attribute value of `method="post"` in the `form` element, but the destination might still have trouble because the site is then getting a POST request, not an expected GET one.

Comment: This hack doesn't work for screen reader users

Answer (score 12):

Just do this

```
<button OnClick=" location.href='link.html' ">Visit Page Now</button>
```

Although, it's been a while since I've touched JavaScript - maybe `location.href` is outdated? Anyways, that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 9):

#### LINKS ARE TRICKY

Consider the tricks that <a href> knows by default but javascript linking won't do for you. On a decent website, anything that wants to behave as a link should implement these features one way or another. Namely:

- **Ctrl+Click: opens link in new tab**
  You can simulate this by using a window.open() with no position/size argument
- **Shift+Click: opens link in new window**
  You can simulate this by window.open() with size and/or position specified
- **Alt+Click: download target**
  People rarely use this one, but if you insist to simulate it, you'll need to write a special script on server side that responds with the proper download headers.

#### EASY WAY OUT

Now if you don't want to simulate all that behaviour, I suggest to use <a href> and style it *like* a button, since the button itself is roughly a shape and a hover effect.  I think if it's not semantically important to only have "the button and nothing else", <a href> is the way of the samurai.  And if you worry about semantics and readability, you can also replace the button element when your document is ready().  It's clear and safe.

Answer (score 6):

Well, for a link, there must be a link tag around. what you can also do is that make a css class for the button and assign that class to the link tag. like,

```css
#btn {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/149/149668.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="btnlink.html" id="btn"></a>
```

Comment: Bootstrap supports this.

<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="...">...</a>

Answer (score 5):

You can make it a non-submitting button (`<button type="button">`) and hook something like `window.location = 'http://where.you.want/to/go'` into its onclick handler. This does not work without javascript enabled though.

Or you can make it a submit button, and do a redirect on the server, although this obviously requires some kind of server-side logic, but the upside is that is doesn't require javascript.

(actually, forget the second solution - if you can't use a form, the submit button is out)

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="portfolio.html">
 <button type="link" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View Work</button>
</form>
```

I just figured this out, and it links perfectly to another page without having my default link settings over ride my button classes! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using jQuery. See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/sQnSZ/

```
<button id="x">test</button>

$('#x').click(function(){
    location.href='http://cnn.com'
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that in your HTML file you've a button with id="Button", In the script.js(your script file), you can use this way:

```
document.getElementById("Button").addEventListener("click", gotoUrl);
    
function gotoUrl() {
       window.location.assign("https://www.google.com/");
    }
```

Now the button will lead you to Google!

For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Comment: There was some mistakes i made in the previous reply. So corrected them. If it still not clear, you can ask me again. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this`<button type=“Submit”><a href=“”>#</a></button>`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid on two counts. `“Submit”` is not a valid value for the `type` attribute (you used the wrong quotes). Buttons are not allowed to contain links.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).