# Browser status bar: Hide address of requests to certain website

Tags: javascript, browser, hide, ip-address, statusbar

I have a website which is requesting (by iframe) another website, which has completely different address. The browser displays a message in the status bar when it is transferring data from those other website. It says: Waiting for reply, then Transfering data from theotherwebsite.com.... and etc. messages.

Is there a way NOT to SHOW the address of the otherwebsite.com down there?
Disabling completely the staus bar is also an option, if there is a proper cross-browser way.

Comment: Instead of using an <a> tag, use <button> instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025941/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-button-element-to-link-to-a-location-without-wrapping

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it for an anchor and using a bit of javascript.

```
<a href="click_counter.php?redirect_to=http://www.google.com/" 
    onmouseover="window.status='Going to google';return true;" 
    onmouseout="window.status='';">Go To Google</a>
```

Edit: Note: The status property does not work in the default configuration of IE, Firefox, Chrome, or Safari. To allow scripts to change the text of the status, the user must set the dom.disable_window_status_change preference to false in the about:config screen. (or in Firefox: "Tools - Options - Content -Enable JavaScript / Advanced - Allow scripts to change status bar text").
From w3schools.. Seems like its no more supported.

Comment: I don't need it for anchors hovering. I just want to remove the "Transfering data from the otherwebsite.com" message when the iframe is loading.

Comment: Then just use some javascript on top which assigns window.status=''; Note that windows.status is no longer supported on many modern browsers.