# Django: button link

Tags: python, html, django

I am a novice Django user trying to create a push button, which links to another page in my site when clicked. I've tried a few different examples which I've found, but none seem to be working for me...

As an example, why is this not working?

```
<form method="link" action="{% url 'gui' %}">
<input type="button" value="Start">
</form>
```

Here, 'gui' is the name I have given to my link in urls.py to the desired page.

I am also fairly new to HTML in general, so it may be my HTML that is wrong...

Thank you.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025941/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-button-element-to-link-to-a-location-without-wrapping

Answer (score 12):

Is there any particular reason you're using both a `form` and a `button`?

Can you use an `a` (anchor tag)?

```
<a href="{% url 'appname.nameOfFunctionInViews' %}">Click here</a>
```

If you want to use a `form`, please post your `urls.py`.

Comment: Or you can use `{% url 'nameoftheURLpattern' %}`

Comment: arocks - yes, that is what I have used in the above example. 'gui' is the name of the URL pattern in my urls.py file.

Comment: The reason I want to use a form, rather than just a link, is because I want it to be styled like a button, rather than a simple text link.

Comment: If you are using, for example `bootstrap` you can simply add `class="btn"` to the input

Answer (score 10):

To create a button that can be clicked and redirect to another link, you can wrap `<button></button>` around `<a></a>`, which worked for me:

```
<button type="button">
    <a href="{% url 'name_of_your_view' %}">Click here!</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'gui' %}">
<button type='submit'>Start</button>
</form>
```

In your views:

```
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'POST'
       # Do something
```

Comment: When answering, please try to explain which changes should be done and why, instead of just posting code without any clarification on what the author was doing wrong.