# Calling view name that belongs to a different app

Tags: html, django

I am trying to a similar task as in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916835/django-button-link/21917002) : calling a view when a button is clicked. However, the view name that the button is calling belongs to a different app.

```
<button class="button table_mgt" >
      <a href="{% url 'table_view' %}">Table Mgt</a>
</button>
```

This button sits in a template called `dashboard.html` which belongs to an app called `account`. But the view named `table_view` belongs to another app called `table`. Both apps belong to the same root.

What do I need to set up for the above code to work?

Update more details:
Here is the error I received:

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/table/tables/
Django Version:     3.0.7
Exception Type:     TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    table_view.html
```

In my `table` app:
File `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('tables/', views.table_view, name='table_view'),
]
```

File `view.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Table

def table_view(request):
    table_num = Table.objects.count()
    return render(request,
                  'table_view.html',
                  {'table_num': table_num})
```

The template `table_view.html` sits in this folder `\table\templates\table\`

File `urls.py` of the project root:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('table/', include('table.urls')),
]
```

In my root project, there is also a folder `\templates` where I keep the `base.html` for all apps to use.

Comment: Normally that will work. The fact that these belong to different apps doesn't matter. If you however have an `app_name` in the `urls.py` of the `table_view`, you need to prefix it with the namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both apps belong to the same project, you do not need to change anything. The fact that these belong to different apps doesn't matter.

If you however have an `app_name` in the `urls.py` of the `table_view`, you need to prefix it with the namespace. For example if the `urls.py` where the `table_view` is defined looks like:

```
# account/urls.py

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('some-path', table_view, name='table_view')
]
```

then you prefix it with the `app_name` in the `urls.py`:

```
<button class="button table_mgt" >
      <a href="{% url 'account:table_view' %}">Table Mgt</a>
</button>
```

The same happens when you defined a `namespace=…` when you included the urls, for example:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    # …,
    path('', include('account.urls', namespace='account')),
]
```

For more information, see the [*URL namespaces* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces).

> The template `table_view.html` sits in this folder `\table\templates\table\`.

Then the name of the template is `table/table_view.html`, so:

```
def table_view(request):
    table_num = Table.objects.count()
    return render(
        request,
        'table/table_view.html',
        {'table_num': table_num}
    )
```

With the default configuration, Django will see all the `templates` directories of all apps as "roots", so, the roots are:

```
app1/templates/
app2/templates/
⋮
appn/templates/
```

you defined in the `templates` directory an extra directory `tables`, so that means that in order to access the `table_view.html`, the path relative to the root is `tables/table_view.html`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I added some more details in my question. I still can't figure out why it cannot find the template ```table_view.html```

Comment: @TristanTran: the name of the template is `table/table_view.html`.

Comment: Thanks. Gotcha ! I changed the ```view.py``` of app ```table``` to render ```table/table_view.html``` instead of ```table_view.html```. And it works. Closing this.