# Can I use a <button> instead of <a> to go to #location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have this code.

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#tab-weekly" data-toggle="tab">Weekly Payment</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#tab-advance" data-toggle="tab">Advance Payment</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#tab-data" data-toggle="tab">Expenses</a>
</li>
```

My question is that can I use `<button>` instead of `<a>` to achieve this? I changed it to buttons but they are not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working ?

Comment: Onclick the div with `id` is not being displayed.

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025941/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-button-element-to-link-to-a-location-without-wrapping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Use `<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='YOUR URL HERE'">Link Text</button>`

Comment: Thankyou. For the help. I tried `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href="reports/daily_report#tab-weekly">Weekly Payment</button>` but not working

Comment: Try replacing the double quotes around your URL with single quotes and make sure to close the quotes around the onclick assignment

Comment: @Ricardo Reyna: You do realize that same mistake was in your answer and the OP was just blindly copying off of it, right?

Comment: Yes, I saw the mistake and edited my response before replying.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `href` in `button` but you can use `data-href` attribute to do this work. When `button` clicked get value of `data-href` and use `window.location.hash` to going to target `id`.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    window.location.hash = $(this).data("href");
});
```

```css
#first, #second, #third {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-href="#first">First</button>
<button data-href="#second">Second</button>
<button data-href="#third">Third</button>

<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/6338065)

Or you can create a `button` with a `<a href>` inside of it. I dont know wat you are trying to achieve with changing it into a button?

```
<button type="button">
   <a href="www.google.com">hello</a>
</button>
```

if it is for the style you can just apply a style to the `a` tag like this `<a href="http://google.com" class="My class">Go to Google</a>`

Goodluck!

Comment: I tried `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href="reports/daily_report#tab-weekly">Weekly Payment</button>` but not working

Comment: OP is trying to use the goto bookmark part of a href, eg `href='#id'` not just create a link to an external website.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use #something in an anchor tag's href attribute it actually take you to an element in same page who's id is 'something'. You can use it like this as well:

```
<a href="http://www.somewhere.com/anotherpage.aspx#something">click</a>
```

In this case it will take you to the anotherpage.aspx page's element who's id is 'something'. 
Now the purpose of button is completely different, but there are some ways to satisfy your requirement but that is not recommended. You should use anchor tag in this situation.

Here is a great link to show the difference between anchor and button tag. [Check it.](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Button does not have `href` functionality, so unless you use some JS functions to simulate this - **No, you can't**

Comment: seems more like a comment.

Comment: @Jai: The question asks, "Can I do this?" And the answer is no. How is it "more like a comment"?

Comment: @BoltClock Then last 3 words should be posted! right...!

Comment: @Jai: I'm sorry but your comment is incomprehensible. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @BoltClock sorry! English is not native language to me, what i meant was _No, you can't_ should only be posted or question should be closed as dupe if any.

Comment: @Jai: The answer is *explaining* why the answer is no! Why would you want someone to post an answer without explanations? And how is the question being a dupe relevant at all to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the styles over `<a class="your-btn-style">` to show your anchor like a button.

If you are using bootstrap, you can simply add class="btn btn-primary" in your anchor for example :

```
<a href="#tab-advance" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tab">Advance Payment</a>
```

I also used this approach in my project :

[image]

Comment: I need button, not a tag :(

Comment: oh :( so you can't use href instead JS

Comment: Yes.. I got it working now. Thanks for your help though.