# vuejs href link not binding to button

Tags: vue.js

In vuejs 2.5, I am trying to bind the href to button. It works great for just traditional hyperlinks, but is there a way to achieve this on a button? Emphasizing that this is specific to vue

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<button v-bind:href="'link.html#/'+$route.params.year+'/12/regulatory?l=something'">My Link</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a <button> element to link to a location without wrapping it in an <a href ... tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025941/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-button-element-to-link-to-a-location-without-wrapping)

Comment: Not a duplicate. In reference to vuejs, how is this done using v-bind

Comment: `<button>` html tag does not has an attribute called `href` so essentially you cannot bind it on button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Href doesnt exist for buttons.
What you can do is to bind it to a `@click` and create a method where you use `window.location = URL`

Answer (score 1):

The `<button>` element does not have an `href` attribute and will not function as a link.

You should instead use an `<a>` with an appropriate button style.