# HTML button to force reload (not using cache) of a static HTML page

Tags: html, css, browser-cache, reload

I've tried several methods, especially all listed here:

- [Button that refreshes the page on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884654/button-that-refreshes-the-page-on-click)
- [Force page reload with html anchors (#) - HTML & JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573979/force-page-reload-with-html-anchors-html-js)

...but they all seem to only trigger a reload using local cache.

Is there any way to trigger a forced reload, bypassing any cache (especially for images) via an HTML button?

Alternatively, is there a line of HTML code that would force the page to not use cache at all?

The page is a simple static html page that changes a few times a day.

Comment: What's the use case? Are you directing users to click the button? Do the linked resources also need cache-busting? More detail, please.

Comment: There are HTML and maybe another assets cached such as images, CSS, JS. For HTML cache, make sure that your page don't have anything functional with some query string like `?v=xx` and then add a button to re-location `'?v=' + date.getTime()` where `date` is JS [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. But this may cause of another problems.

Comment: It would be best if users didn't have to click a button, and the page would always load without using cache instead. This is only about cached images, other assets are not critical and do not necessarily need to be reloaded.

Comment: _Is there any way to trigger a forced reload, bypassing any cache (especially for images) via an HTML button?_

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML-only way to do it.

You could try using `window.location.reload(true)` which will try to reload the current page and ignore cache files on some browsers. But this is not part of the specification and won't work on most browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

---

The **real** way to make it is to version your filenames ! There are many tools to do it quite easily. When the page will refresh, as the name will have changed, your browser is going to load the new file and you won't have cache problem anymore

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to force reload (+ clear cache) in HTML itself.

One solution is to make a button and give that a JS function, in which both the cache is cleared and the page reloaded.

```
function reloadClear() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload(true);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I would love to try this. Unfortunately I don't know whether it's possible to include your code in my pure HTML page, and if so, where?

Comment: You could just put a <script> tag before closing the <body>. In that script, put the function, and link that to an onClick on the button.

Comment: Awesome, will try -- would you mind showing me how to link that to an HTML button?

Comment: Ah I believe I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5025990/1388921

Comment: Could this script also be auto-run before the page loads?

Comment: I tried your script and linked it to a button. While it reloads the page, the browsers (Chrome or Edge) still use the cached images. I am at a loss what to do now?

Comment: Could you instead try to randomize a number, add that to a variable, and put that in the reload link?

e.g. `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);`

and then changing the reload link to:
`window.location = location.href + '?r=' + random;`

Comment: You could run this script [onPageLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842614/how-do-i-call-a-javascript-function-on-page-load) instead of on a button click, yes; **although that would cause an infinite reload loop.**

Answer (score 0):

just remove localstorage saved files use **window.localstorage.remove('name of the item you saved')**
or if you didnt what all of them just use **window.localstorage.clear()** then reload it with **window.location.reload(true)**

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work: the browser still uses the cached images.